# Open-ended pipe under water, pressure vs. flow when pump starts up

Tags: hydrodynamics

A pipe with a pump and two open ends is placed under water. When the pump is initially turned on, will the pressure at P_out and P_in initially rise/fall, but then stabilize as a flow of water V_flux develops (and the suction pressure is equal to the pushing pressure at all points)? The assumption is that the pressure from the pump first travels as a compression and rarefaction wave, and then once those meet and a flow forms, they cancel out to some extent.

[image]